# Checking if the data being retrieved from the database Eager loading OR lazy is loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following two models; AccountDefinition & SDOrganization where the relation is one-to-one.

```
public partial class AccountDefinition
    {
        public AccountDefinition()
        {
            this.AccountSiteMappings = new HashSet<AccountSiteMapping>();
        }

        public long ORG_ID { get; set; }


        public virtual SDOrganization SDOrganization { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccountSiteMapping> AccountSiteMappings { get; set; }}
```

&

```
public partial class SDOrganization
    {
        public SDOrganization()
        {
            this.AccountAttachments = new HashSet<AccountAttachment>();
            this.SDOrgUsers = new HashSet<SDOrgUser>();
            this.AaaContactInfoes = new HashSet<AaaContactInfo>();
            this.AaaUsers = new HashSet<AaaUser>();
            this.AaaPostalAddresses = new HashSet<AaaPostalAddress>();
        }

        public long ORG_ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }        


        public virtual AccountDefinition AccountDefinition { get; set; }
        public virtual SDOrgDetail SDOrgDetail { get; set; }
        public virtual SDOrgStatu SDOrgStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SDOrgUser> SDOrgUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AaaContactInfo> AaaContactInfoes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AaaUser> AaaUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AaaPostalAddress> AaaPostalAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

On the Action method I have the following call to the repository:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null)
        {
var accountdefinition = repository.FindAccountDefinition(searchTerm).ToList();

if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                ViewBag.FromSearch = true;
                return PartialView("_CustomerTable",accountdefinition);
            }

            return View(accountdefinition);        
        }
```

And the repository the method looks as :-

```
public IQueryable<AccountDefinition> FindAccountDefinition(string q)
        {
            return from ad in entities.AccountDefinitions.Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
                   where (q == null || ad.ORG_NAME.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()) )
                   select ad;


        }
```

Finally on the view I got the following code (only part of the code):-

```
@model IEnumerable<TMS.Models.AccountDefinition>
//code goes here
<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SUPPORT_EMAIL)
        </th>
      <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Single().SDOrganization.DESCRIPTION)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
//code goes here
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
   <td class="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SDOrganization.DESCRIPTION)

        </td>
```

I am assuming that since on the repository method I added the .include
return from ad in

```
entities.AccountDefinitions.Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
```

So all the data regarding the accountdefinition and the SDorganization will be retrieved at once (eager loading).
so I have the following two questions:-

1. Will in my case the data retrieved by a single query to the database (Eager Loading).
2. I am using SQL server 2008 r2. So how I can check the database queries to check how many query actually hit the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you are using `.Include()` method you are initiating eager loading. So yes your data will be returned by single query.
2. For checking it consider to use [SQL Server Profiler](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/sql-server-2008-profiler-and-tuning-wizard) or paid utility [Entity Framework profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf). Also such utility as [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx) could help you in query tracing

Also you need to be careful with repositories returning IQueryable because usage like this will execute several queries in a loop:

```
foreach(var accDef in repository.FindAccountDefinition(searchTerm))
{
    //get info from accDef
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my above case your example does  not apply.? right?

Comment: Yes, you call .ToList() and get result of query in objects in memory so you are ok with that.